# Return value optimization of tuple/tie

Tags: c++, c++11, stdtuple, rvo

I am looking into return value optimization in the case of tuple/ties and the behavior I observe is not as I expected. In the example below I would expect move semantics to kick in, which it does, but there is one copy operation which remains. The output from the below in optimized is:

```
Test duo output, non_reference tuple
Default constructor invoked
Parameter constructor invoked
Copy constructor invoked
Move Assignment operator invoked
100
```

The invocation of the copy constructor in making the tuple inside the function seems unnecessary. Is there any way to remove this? I am using the MSVC 2012 compiler.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

class A
{
public:
     int value;
     A() : value(-1)
     {
         std::cout << "Default constructor invoked" << std::endl;
     }

     explicit A(const int v) : value(v)
     {
         std::cout << "Parameter constructor invoked" << std::endl;
     }

     A(const A& rhs)
     {
         value = rhs.value;
         std::cout << "Copy constructor invoked" << std::endl;
     }

     A(const A&& rhs)
     {
         value = rhs.value;
         std::cout << "Move constructor invoked" << std::endl;
     }

     A& operator=(const A& rhs)
     {
         value = rhs.value;
         std::cout << "Assignment operator invoked" << std::endl;
         return *this;
     }

     A& operator=(const A&& rhs)
     {
         value = rhs.value;
         std::cout << "Move Assignment operator invoked" << std::endl;
         return *this;
     }
 };

 std::tuple<A, int> return_two_non_reference_tuple()
 {
     A tmp(100);

     return std::make_tuple(tmp, 99);
 }

 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {

      std::cout << "Test duo output, non_reference tuple" << std::endl;    
      A t3;
      int v1;
      std::tie(t3, v1) = return_two_non_reference_tuple();
      std::cout << t3.value << std::endl << std::endl;

      system("pause");
      return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The move constructor will not be called automatically because you are calling

```
std::make_tuple(tmp, 99);
```

In this case, `tmp` is an lvalue. You can use `std::move` to cast it to an rvalue reference:

```
return std::make_tuple(std::move(tmp), 99);
```

This will instruct the compiler to use the move constructor.

Answer (score 6):

The copy occurs here:

```
std::make_tuple(tmp, 99);
```

Although you can see that `tmp` might be able to be directly constructed in the tuple, the copy from `tmp` to the tuple will not be elided. What you really want is a way to pass in arguments for `std::tuple` to use to construct its internal `A` and `int` objects. There isn't such a thing for `std::tuple`, but there is a way to achieve the same effect.

Since you only have two types, you could use `std::pair`. This has a `std::piecewise_construct` constructor, which takes two `std::tuples` containing the arguments to pass to the constructors of the internal objects.

```
 std::pair<A, int> return_two_non_reference_tuple()
 {
     return {std::piecewise_construct, 
             std::make_tuple(100), std::make_tuple(99)};
 }
```

The cool thing about this solution is that you can still use `std::tie` at the call site, because `std::tuple` has an assignment operator from `std::pair`.

```
std::tie(t3, v1) = return_two_non_reference_tuple();
```

As you can see from the output, your copy is gone. It isn't replaced by a move like in the other answers, it's totally removed:

> Test duo output, non_reference tuple
>
> Default constructor invoked
>
> Parameter constructor invoked
>
> Move Assignment operator invoked
>
> 100

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d844209e4d5b280)

Comment: Thanks, its a good alternative for the simple case, but if there is more actions done on tmp, and more outputs, it wouldnt work. And I dont think it would work in MSVC 2012.

Comment: Copy elision is happening here. The problem is that `tmp` is not being moved into the `tuple`. The copy constructor is from copying `tmp` into the tuple, not the tuple being copied.

Comment: @Simple I know that, maybe my answer isn't clear enough.

Comment: @thorsan If there are more actions to be done on `tmp`, you could execute them on the element of the pair, then let the return of the pair be elided through NRVO.

Comment: @TartanLlama no. You cannot rely on (N)RVO as this is merely an optional optimization compilers can employ but are not required to. As a matter of fact. MSVC 17 (visual studio 15.3) doesn't support NRVO in debug mode (only RVO) but it does support both in release mode. (I just tested). However, c++17 introduces guaranteed copy elision. This you CAN rely on (if you compiler supports it yet). It prevents the need to construct (materialize) a temporary all together when it is not needed.

Comment: c++17 even allows you to `auto [t3, v1] = return_two_non_reference_tuple()` (Structured Bindings).

Answer (score 4):

The copy takes place in `return_two_non_reference_tuple()`.

One way to remove it is to move `tmp`

```
std::tuple<A, int> return_two_non_reference_tuple()
{
    A tmp(100);
    return std::make_tuple(std::move(tmp), 99);
}
```

or another way

```
std::tuple<A, int> return_two_non_reference_tuple()
{
    return std::make_tuple(A(100), 99);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not moving `tmp`:

```
 A tmp(100);

 return std::make_tuple(std::move(tmp), 99);
```